# Compiling modules in different directories

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

I'm trying to follow these instructions to compile a module that depends on another module which I've created: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html

In my case, I have a module `~/courseFiles/chapter5/moduleA.ml` and another module in `~/OCamlCommons/listMethods.ml`.  I have compiled `listMethods.ml` using `ocamlopt -c listMethods.ml` and this seemed to work, it produced a file `listMethods.cmx`.

The file `moduleA.ml` contains `open ListMethods;;`.  Now with my terminal located at `~/courseFiles/chapter5` I ran `ocamlopt -c moduleA.ml` but the terminal returns

> Error: Unbound module ListMethods

Now I can understand why it would do this, but the instructions at that site seem to indicate that what I've done is how you're supposed to do this.  Presumably I need to pass in the location of either the script or executable files when compiling `moduleA.ml`, but I'm not sure what the syntax should be.  I've tried a few guesses, and guessed about how I could do this with `ocamlfind` but I haven't succeeded.  I tried looking for instructions on compiling modules located in different directories but didn't find anything (or anything I can make sense of anyway).

Comment: Use the `-I` option, e.g. `ocamlopt -I ~/OCamlCommons -c moduleA.ml`. See `man ocamlopt` or http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual025.html

Comment: I also suggest you learn how to use an automated build system, such as [`dune`](https://github.com/ocaml/dune), to prevent the hassle of manual compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the toolkit that is shipped with the OCaml System Distribution (aka the compiler) is very versatile but quite low-level and should be seen as a foundation layer for building more high-level build systems. Therefore, learning it is quite hard and usually makes sense only if you're going to build such systems. It is *much* easier to learn how to use [dune](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [oasis](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/setting_up_with_oasis.html) or [ocamlbuild](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc) instead. Moreover, it will diverge your attention from what actually matters - learning the language.

With all that said, let me answer your question in full details. OCaml implements a separate compilation scheme, where each compilation unit could be built independently and then linked into a single binary. This scheme is common in C/C++ languages, and in fact, OCaml compiler toolchain is very similar to the C compiler toolchain.

When you run `ocamlopt -c x.ml` you're creating a compilation unit, and as a result a few files are produced, namely:

- `x.o` - contains actually the compiled machine code
- `x.cmx` - contains optimization data and other compiler-specific information
- `x.cmi` - contains compiled interface to the module `X`.

In order to compile a module, the compiler doesn't need the code of any other modules used in that module. But what it needs is the typing information, i.e., it needs to know what is the type of `List.find` function, or a type of any other function that is provided by some module which is external to your module. This information is stored in cmi files, for which (compiled) header files from C/C++ is the closest counterpart. As in C/C++ the compiler is searching for them in the include search path, which by default includes the current directory and the location of the standard library, but could be extended using the `-I` option (the same as in C/C++). Therefore, if your module is using another module defined in a folder `A` you need to tell the compiler where to search for it, e.g.,

```
 ocamlopt -I A -c x.ml
```

The produced objective file will not contain any code from external modules. Therefore, once you will reach the final stage of compilation - the linking phase, you have to provide the implementation, e.g., if your module `X` was using a module implemented in a file with relative path `A/y.ml`, and you have compiled it in that folder, then you need to specify again the location of the compiled implementation, e.g.,

```
 ocamlopt -I A y.cmx x.cmx -o exe
```

The order is important, all modules used by a module should be specified before that module, otherwise, you will get the "No implementations provided" error.

As you can see, it is a pretty convoluted process, and it is really not worthwhile to invest your time in learning it. So, if you have an option, then use a higher-level tool to build your programs. If not sure, then choose Dune :)